# .Contains with a list as variable

Tags: asp.net, linq, c#-4.0

I am trying to parse a comma delimited text box as a list and then check if a string has any of the strings in the list.

For instance:
txtLastName: smit txtFirstName: joh,jon,j.

I need to search a database that has a field combined_name that includes smith and joh or jon or j. in it.

This is what I have so far:

```
            var fullName = txtSearchBox0.Text.Trim();
        List<string> firstName = new List<string>(txtSearchBox1.Text.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToString(x)).ToList());


        var rows = (from c in db.GetTable<defendants_ALL>()
                    where c.combined_name.Contains(fullName) && c.combined_name.Contains(firstName)
                    select c).ToList();
```

This does not work with firstName being a list but it does if it is var like the last name.  Is it possible to use .Contains with the list variable or is there another way I need to do this??

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.

Try searching the value in the first name list as

```
string fullName = txtSearchBox0.Text.Trim();
List<string> firstName = txtSearchBox1.Text.Split(',').ToList();

var rows = (from c in db.GetTable<defendants_ALL>()
            where c.combined_name.Contains(fullName) 
                && firstName.Contains(c.combined_name)
            select c)
           .ToList();
```